# How to specify height in jquery css method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to set height for div element in the form of percentage. not by pixel wise.

```
$("#div1").height("200px");
```

so how should I set this in percentage wise?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#div1").css("height", "20%");
```

sets the height to `20%` of the element with id `div1`

Answer (score 3):

you might need to set your `body` and `html` tag to 100%.

```
//css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

then just change the `px` to `%`

```
$("#div1").height("20%");
```